# c++ typedef generics

Tags: c++, generics, typedef

I have this typedef in Ogre3D:

```
namespace Ogre {
    typedef vector<String>::type StringVector;
    ...
}
```

What is the "::" operator for? Does it do anything? As it is, I think this is a vector of strings - a StringVector. Correct?

Comment: This is not the whole `typedef`.

Comment: `type` is some entity (obviously, a type) declared inside `vector` class. `::` operator is used to reference element `type` from `vector` namespace.

Comment: @VioletGiraffe - `vector` could be a class also (for example, if it's `std::vector`)

Comment: @meh: yes, i have edited it to show full typedef

Comment: `::` is the scope resolution operator. If you are not familiar with this (a basic syntax element of C++), I suggest you read a [good book](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/388242/the-definitive-c-book-guide-and-list).

Comment: I am familiar with this operator, but I should have made my question more precise. I wanted to know what the construct "::type" does in the context of typedef here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Defines a type `StringVector` which is `vector<String>::type`.

It seems like `type` is a type, defined inside `vector` (which is `template class`)

`::` is called "scope resolution operator".

Comment: Yes actually now I found this further definition of type: typedef std::vector< T, A > type
The Vector is an STL Vector (std::vector)

Comment: So I see, this is the way needed for a typedef from a template class. Could the identifier "type" be substituted by any identifier like "foo" etc.?

Comment: @MichiMichbeck - if `foo` is a type, defined in the class/namespace before the scope resolution operator - then yes, `foo` can substitute `type`.

Answer (score 0):

`type` is some entity (obviously, a type) declared inside `vector` class. `::` operator is used to reference element `type` from `vector` namespace.

P. S. By saying "namespace" I don't only mean the actual C++ `namespace` feature, since classes are also similar to namespaces in that they can have nested definitions.